# Error when setting a route for page navigation

Tags: angularjs-routing

I am trying to set a route for page navigation in my app, but getting below error:

> ERROR in C:/my-app/src/app/router.component.ts (9,2): Type '({ Path: string; redirectTo: string; PathMatch: string; } | { Path: string; component: typeof Abo...' is not assignable to type 'Route[]'.   Type '{ Path: string; redirectTo: string; PathMatch: string; } | { Path: string; component: typeof Abou...' is not assignable to type 'Route'.

Code:

```
export const router: Routes=[
    {Path:'', redirectTo:'about', PathMatch:'full'},
    {Path:'about', component:AboutComponent},
    {Path:'products', component:ProductsComponent},
];
```

Comment: Looking at the docs here: https://angular.io/api/router/Routes the path property should be lowercase?

Comment: If any answer has helped you, could you please accept or upvote it? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for help, I corrected my code and the got the expected result. This post saved my time.Thank you so much

Comment: @BhavaniRaju great! So can you please accept and upvote the answer that helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Try without uppercase:

```
  export const router: Routes=[
  {path:'', redirectTo:'about', pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'about', component: AboutComponent},
  {path:'products', component: ProductsComponent},

   ];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you see these `is not assignable to type 'X'` exceptions, it is because the structure of the object literals don't match the Assignment structure (case-sensitive). This becomes clear when we check the Route interface:

```
export interface Route {
    path?: string;
    pathMatch?: string;
    matcher?: UrlMatcher;
    component?: Type<any>;
    redirectTo?: string;
    outlet?: string;
    canActivate?: any[];
    canActivateChild?: any[];
    canDeactivate?: any[];
    canLoad?: any[];
    data?: Data;
    resolve?: ResolveData;
    children?: Routes;
    loadChildren?: LoadChildren;
    runGuardsAndResolvers?: RunGuardsAndResolvers;
}
```

As with most properties in javascript, `path` and `pathMatch` are defined in camel-case.

```
export const router: Routes = [
  {path:'', redirectTo:'about', pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'about', component:AboutComponent},
  {path:'products', component:ProductsComponent}
];
```